# Are there examples of objects that are, but may not seem like they are, in free fall?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, acceleration, free-fall

Is it possible for a plane to be in free fall while it is in the sky? If not, what is an example of an object that is, but may not seem like it is, in free fall?

Comment: Technically speaking _No_ because of drag.

Comment: Satellites and the international space station for example are in free fall around the earth.

Answer (score 1):

A body is in "free fall" when the only net force it is subjected to is gravity.

Aeroplanes, or anything else in the earth's atmosphere, cannot be in free fall due to air resistance and potentially other factors. As pointed out in the other answers, the "vomit comet" comes close, but, as Qmechanic points out, *technically* it cannot be in free fall.

Something that was never intuitive to me when I was younger is that all celestial bodies (planets, comets, spacecraft, etc) are in fact in free fall basically permanently.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a ride on the [vomit comet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced-gravity_aircraft&ved=0ahUKEwjo_c_InaLPAhUI5IMKHfaaBuIQFggkMAI&usg=AFQjCNH-Tax8wVf8gIaVZZiz3YQ1Nxlo5A&sig2=BDZb6sVEputWqkL1UiXBRg)

Answer (score 0):

Are you taking about reduced gravity aircraft? They don't do free fall, but a controlled fall of around 1.5-2g. During free fall, the acceleration of the object is just g. To fall at g, you have to switch off the aircraft's engine completely. I have heard of some fighter pilots doing it, but I don't know how far that's true. Also, even if you are falling free, there will be air-drag as well, so your acceleration is g-air drag, so in order to maintain the g, you need to accelerate to nullify the effect or air drag.